# Evaporate water using compressed air

Tags: energy, evaporation

I want to evaporate water by forming air bubbles which are formed by flow of compresses air through perforations.

What is the energy (in KWh) input to compress 1 cubic meter volume of atmospheric air to 50 bar ? What will be the temparature of the compressed air if ambient temperature is 30 degree celcius ?

If I compress atmospheric air to 50 bar then to evaporate 1 litre of water how much volume of air has to be compressed and supplied ?

For any missing constants please assume and let me know.

Is this process efficient or inefficient when compared to direct boiling of water ?
How much energy (KWh) is needed for direct evaporation of water (lets say a heating coil in a vessel) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding Floris's comment on engineering details, surface contact area will affect the efficiency in the heat transfer, so more smaller bubbles are better than a few bigger ones. I've done similar experiments and found using a pumice stone, like those used to aerate aquariums work very well in finely dividing the air bubbles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume adiabatic compression, [the equations are](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/adiab.html)

$$PV^\gamma = K \text{ (constant)}\tag1$$

Where for air (mostly a diatomic gas), $\gamma=\frac75$. This means that the final volume $V_f$ when the pressure is 50 bar (50x atmospheric) is

$$V_f = V_i \left(\frac{P_i}{P_f}\right)^\frac{1}{\gamma} = 61.2 L$$

The temperature of the gas is given by the ideal gas law:

$$PV = nRT\\
T_f = T_i\frac{P_i V_i}{P_f V_f} = 928 K = $$

and we find $T_f = 655 °C$

The work done is then given by

$$W = K\frac{V_f^{1-\gamma} - V_i^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}\tag2$$

Substituting the initial conditions into (1) we eliminate $K$ from (2) and get

$$W = P_i V_i^\gamma\frac{V_f^{1-\gamma} - V_i^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}=-5.1 \mathrm{\;bar\; m^3} = 0.14 \mathrm{\;kWh}\tag2$$

for the power required to compress 1 cubic meter of ambient air to a pressure of 50 bar.

The resulting hot air could be used to heat water - but recognize that the air expanding into the water will undergo adiabatic cooling, so you would have to keep the water at the higher pressure in order to take advantage of the heat in the air, and then you end up with steam at this higher pressure as well...

And in this process, all we did was use mechanical energy to generate heat; and while the next step of the process (using small bubbles of hot air to evaporate water) is probably quite efficient (in terms of heat transfer), the first step (convert electrical energy to hot air by compression) is probably not - and you end up with steam at a pressure which might not be useful for you.

So unless you have a source of mechanical energy (say, a windmill) and you need the steam at a high pressure, I think this is not a good method for evaporating water. If you put an electrical heating element in direct contact with the water, all the electrical power is directly converted into heat, and thus into steam. I think it would be a better approach.

In general, a heating element in water would need to heat the water (from 30C to 100 C), then supply additional heat to convert the water to steam. The heat capacity of water is about 4.2 kJ/kg/°C, and the latent heat of evaporation is 2260 J/g. This means the total energy needed to boil one liter of water initially at 30C is

$$E = (100-30)*4.2 + 2260 = 2.5 MJ = 0.71 kWh$$

Note most of this energy is to actually evaporate the water, not to heat it up. It also tells us that if the evaporating is done in order to distill the water, we can get a LOT more energy efficient by condensing the steam using the incoming (dirty) water - the water will be heated "for free" by the steam, and the steam will turn back into (clean) water.

All this quickly turns into engineering... I recommend that if you have follow up questions, you direct them to engineering.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Very nice answer. One should point out that in most technical applications the compression is closer to isothermal because it's not a good idea to get pressure vessels hot, so one would use a heat exchanger to cool the gas at least partially. This is a serious problem for both compressed air cars and compressed air underground energy storage caverns... the roundtrip efficiency is greatly diminished by the loss of the heat during compression and the gas needs to be reheated before running trough the expansion engines.

Comment: @CuriousOne - thanks, those are very valid points, but if you are trying to evaporate water by running compressed air through it, you need at least use the heat to warm the water. But your comment gets to the heart of the issue - this is probably not a good idea...

Comment: I totally agree, that's exactly one of the major technical problems with all schemes that use compressed gases and not just for this application. The OP's "application" may be on the niche side, but for real world stuff the difference between adiabatic and isothermal is quite a game changer, especially at higher compression ratios.

Comment: Thank Floris ! Currently we are employing direct heating of the vessel using firewood which is a cheaper form of energy but its not efficient and not a good environment friendly solution. Can you tell me how to calculate amount of water that can be evaporated with the compressed air at 3 bar ? I want to explore the possibility of spreading a thin layer of water (0.5 feet) over a wide area (10 x 10 feet) and employ bubbles to increase evaporation over surface. Is there a way to calculate such evaporation ?

Comment: Ideally I want to compress air to make bubbles. In the enclosed volume I then want to create suction/vacuum.

Comment: @madankandula can you explain the application a little more? Are you interested in drying / concentrating something or do you need the water vapor? Do you have sun light available? It is very effective and cheap. And you live in India...

Comment: I am interested in concentrating a salt solution from 6% to 20%. We employ 3 stage evaporator using a thermic fluid. Yes we are in India and we have sunlight and the average temparature is 35-40 C. There is open area with sunlight ~30,000 SFT. I want to see if this space can be utilized for free evaporation and feed the rest to the 3 stage evaporator.

Comment: Thin layer of liquid, dark surface to bottom of container, flow liquid slowly from one end of the tank to the other, and add a small "breeze" (air flow removing vapor) - that will give you a very effective evaporator. Note that as salt concentration goes up, keeping the relative humidity of the air above low becomes more important. Hence the need to flow warm dry air over the solution.

Comment: Is there a way to caculate such surface evaporation ? The humidity in the air is pretty low as its a dry area and there will be sunshine.

Comment: humidity if 50%